# Playing “craps” for the win v0.2

Tags: java, beginner, game, random, dice

Continued from [Playing "craps" for the win](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/68870/playing-craps-for-the-win?noredirect=1#comment125786_68870)

> You roll two dice. Each die has six faces, which contain one, two,
>   three, four, five and six spots, respectively. After the dice have
>   come to rest, the sum of the spots on the two upward faces is
>   calculated. If the sum is 7 or 11 on the first throw, you win. If the
>   sum is 2, 3 or 12 on the first throw (called “craps”), you lose (i.e.,
>   the “house” wins). If the sum is 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 or 10 on the first
>   throw, that sum becomes your “point.” To win, you must continue
>   rolling the dice until you “make your point” (i.e., roll that same
>   point value). You lose by rolling a 7 before making your point.

```
// Craps.java

package co.vu.xxx.craps;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Craps {
    private int point;
    public static enum possibleResults {UNDEFINED, WIN, LOSE};
    protected possibleResults gameResult;
    private String cause;
    private static SecureRandom randomNumbers = new SecureRandom();

    public Craps() {
        gameResult = possibleResults.UNDEFINED;
    }

    public static int rollDice() {
        int randN = 2 + randomNumbers.nextInt(6) + randomNumbers.nextInt(6);
        System.out.printf("Rolling dice... You got %d%n", randN);
        return randN;
    }

    public void firstRoll() throws IOException {
        waitUser();
        int tmp = rollDice();
        switch (tmp) {
            case 7:case  11:
                gameResult = possibleResults.WIN;
                cause= String.format("you have got a lucky number in the first round: %d.", tmp);
                break;
            case 2:case 3:case 12:
                gameResult = possibleResults.LOSE;
                cause= String.format("you have got an unlucky number in the first round: %d.", tmp);
                break;
            default:
                point = tmp;
        }
    }

    public void declareResult() {
        if(point != 0) {
            System.out.printf("You need to make your point: %d%n", point);
        }
        switch (gameResult) {
            case LOSE:
                System.out.printf("You have lost, because %s%n", cause);
                break;
            case WIN:
                System.out.printf("You have won, because %s%n", cause);
                break;
            case UNDEFINED:
                System.out.println("Game continues...\n");
                break;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void moreRolls() {
        waitUser();
        int tmp = rollDice();
        if(tmp == point) {
            gameResult = possibleResults.WIN;
            cause = "you have made your point!";
        } else if(tmp == 7) {
            gameResult = possibleResults.LOSE;
            cause = "you have hit 7 before making your point.";
        }
    }

    private void waitUser() {
        Scanner inputScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Press enter to start rolling: ");
        String input = inputScan.nextLine();
    }
}
```

---

```
// UseCraps.java

package co.vu.xxx.craps;

import java.io.IOException;

public class UseCraps {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Craps crapObj = new Craps();
        crapObj.firstRoll();
        crapObj.declareResult();
        while(crapObj.gameResult == Craps.possibleResults.UNDEFINED) {
            crapObj.moreRolls();
            crapObj.declareResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At a glance, the code looks reasonably good.

Either initialize everything in the constructor:

```
protected possibleResults gameResult;
private static SecureRandom randomNumbers;

public Craps() {
    this.gameResult = possibleResults.UNDEFINED;
    this.randomNumbers = new SecureRandom();
}
```

… or get rid of the constructor completely (it is implicit):

```
protected possibleResults gameResult = possibleResults.UNDEFINED;
private static SecureRandom randomNumbers = new SecureRandom();
```

---

There is a curious mix of private and protected members.  Why?  I suggest making them all private unless you see a need to expose them.

The `gameResult` member should be made private; other classes should have to call a public method `getResult()` to retrieve it.  That prevents other code from setting the `gameResult`.

---

As an enum, `possibleResults` should follow the naming conventions for classes (beginning with a capital letter).  I suggest shortening the name to

```
public static enum Outcome { UNDEFINED, WIN, LOSE };
```

Putting it as the first thing in the `Craps` class would be good, so as to avoid interrupting the class definition with an enum definition.

Answer (score 5):

Your `Craps` class should keep its responsibilities limited to playing the game and not printing out and passing around messages. This makes the class more flexible.

To this end, your `possibleResults` enum should actually have more states describing the different win and loss conditions. You can have states like `WIN_NATURAL`, `WIN_POINT`, `LOSE_CRAPS`, and `LOSE_SEVEN`. Then these states can be distinguished by the calling class and `Craps` no longer has to pass around and display messages.

Then you can move all of the message generation to the `UseCraps` class. This enables any class that wants to use `Craps` to display messages on the command line, or in a GUI, or however else without binding them to `System.out`. You should also move the waiting done by `waitUser()` to `UseCraps`. Then `UseCraps` (or any other consumer) can decide how to pause in its event loop (or not pause at all) rather than being restricted to `System.in`.

Also, everything that @200_success said.